# Scrolling:"no" when performing window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, forward

Is it possible that when user is sent to another page to disable the scrollbar?

I don't want to run anything in the final page itself but in the page that the user first lands on (where they will be forwarded) or iframes isn't an option either.

I have tried to use two options: over-flow hidden and scrolling no.

The script I am using itself is sort of a randomiser of which page it is forwarded to:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.location = URLlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * URLlist.length)];}, reDelay);
```

Comment: try `overflow:hidden` (instead of `over-flow:hidden`)

Comment: It depends if the page is internal or an external page. If it is internal you can do with some css and if it's external you can load the page in a popup in an iframe and control the scrollbar there. Can you give in some more information?

Comment: You can not control a page from another page. That other page needs to have logic in it..

Comment: Thanks. Both pages are mine but I am using site.com/#content where the user's final destination is #content I want them to not be able to scroll up or down ie scrollbar no